# How much more efficient is sending a certain amount of data from server to client vs client to server?

Tags: java, performance, networking, stream

Let's say I'm sending a large amount of data from a server to a client. What are the inner workings behind reading/writing a stream? Is it more efficient for the server to read from a stream, rather than write to it? In other words, if I send the same amount of data from client to server, is it faster (on the server's side) than going from server to client?

My hunch is that it's more efficient for the server to read rather than write, but I'm having trouble understanding exactly what causes this to happen!

EDIT: Let's assume we're working with streams in Java, using TCP.

Answer (score 1):

After the connection is established, TCP works symmetrically - you shouldn't see a performance difference from swapping which host is the server and which host is the client.

That doesn't mean that data flow will be the same in both directions - imagine a network connection with more bandwidth in one direction than the other, such as ADSL.

It's possible that some router in the middle of your connection might decide to act differently depending on which host is the server. I haven't heard of this happening, but it's theoretically possible - if your ISP was particularly evil, they could do that in order to discourage people from running servers on their residential connections. But it *shouldn't* happen.

Comment: Here's a more concrete situation. Suppose I was writing a set of "potential" data from client to server (which is a large list) then the server refines that data and writes the "actual" data back to the client. Is this slower (on the server's side) than the server just writing all the "potential" data in the first place, then having the client process it locally?

Comment: @Ashok That's not a more concrete situation, it is a completely different question. In the first case the data is sent in both directions: in the second case it is only sent in one direction.*Ergo* the second case is twice as fast, unless the network is asymmetrical.

Comment: @Ashok If you're transferring less data, then it (probably) takes less time to transfer. If you're transferring more data, it (probably) takes more time. "(probably)" only because there's no way to know for certain, other than measuring it.

Answer (score -1):

> How much more efficient is sending a certain amount of data from server to client vs client to server?

Zero. There is no difference.

> What are the inner workings behind reading/writing a stream?

Too broad.

> Is it more efficient for the server to read from a stream, rather than write to it?

No.

> In other words, if I send the same amount of data from client to server, is it faster (on the server's side) than going from server to client?

That's a different question. If the network is asymmetrical, yes, otherwise no.

> My hunch is that it's more efficient for the server to read rather than write, but I'm having trouble understanding exactly what causes this to happen!

It doesn't happen, so there is nothing to understand. Your hunch is baseless speculation. TCP/IP is fully symmetrical (after the initial connect phase in the case of TCP).

Comment: I only realized my question was this broad a while after I posted it. I knew someone was going to say this! I've edited my question to create a more concrete situation.

Comment: Whether you're working with streams and/or in Java makes zero difference, and I had already assumed you were talking about TCP.